# How to obfuscate files without using any external libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption, password-protection

I am currently trying to obscure the contents of files or simply txt files without using any libraries. I know that this won't be very secure at all but what I basically want is a program that asks you what the password to "encrypt" it with is, then it asks what the files name is and then it finds that file and "encrypts" it. Then another program is used to "decrypt" it so it asks for the password and filename and then "decrypts" it. I don't care about actual security so if it can be easily opened it's fine I just need it so it doesn't just open if you click the file.

On top of that I don't want it to use ANY libraries so no pycrypto or anything like that.

I am on 64 bit windows.

I also am a complete beginner in tthe world of code and only know basic things such as how to get user input, print stuff, if loops and while loops.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the extension to something your OS does not recognize. Then clicking it will not open it (directly). But that is not secure at all.

Comment: Maybe rephrase to externally library? Everything you  don't install additionally is the *standard library*

Comment: Repeat after me: **I will not roll my own crypto!** Repeat until you believe it.

Comment: @zwer The OP is not looking for crypto, but rather obfuscation. "I don't care about actual security..."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this qualifies as an "external library" in your mind, but if you're on a linux machine you probably have the `gpg` command available to you. This is a reasonably* secure encryption protocol, which you could access from python - or directly from the command line, if you just want the files protected and you don't care about having it done through python.

Alternatively, you could bang together a trivial mechanism for obscuring a file's contents based on a known password. For example, you could "stretch" the password to the length of the file text (multiply the string by (1 + (text length / password length)) and then zip the two together. This gives you a bunch of tuples, which can by converted to their ordinal value (`ord('f')`=>102, for example) and xored together (`ord('f')^ord('b')`=>4) and converted back to chars (chr(4) => the unprintable '\x04'). The resulting chars are your cyphertext.
All of this is trivial to break, of course, but it's easy to implement, and decryption is trivial.

*intentional understatement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `password` as a key to encrypt it. May be a logical operation on the file on a binary level such as `or`, `and`, or others will be able to encrypt it very simply -- but it won't be secure like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) (xTended Tiny Encryption Algorithm) by copying the [python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496737-python-xtea-encryption/) (xTended Tiny Encryption Algorithm) code into your project, it is only 28 lines of python. It has been subjected to [cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA#Cryptanalysis) and shown to be reasonably secure.

```
import struct

def crypt(key,data,iv='\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00',n=32):
    def keygen(key,iv,n):
        while True:
            iv = xtea_encrypt(key,iv,n)
            for k in iv:
                yield ord(k)
    xor = [ chr(x^y) for (x,y) in zip(map(ord,data),keygen(key,iv,n)) ]
    return "".join(xor)

def xtea_encrypt(key,block,n=32,endian="!"):
    v0,v1 = struct.unpack(endian+"2L",block)
    k = struct.unpack(endian+"4L",key)
    sum,delta,mask = 0L,0x9e3779b9L,0xffffffffL
    for round in range(n):
        v0 = (v0 + (((v1<<4 ^ v1>>5) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]))) & mask
        sum = (sum + delta) & mask
        v1 = (v1 + (((v0<<4 ^ v0>>5) + v0) ^ (sum + k[sum>>11 & 3]))) & mask
    return struct.pack(endian+"2L",v0,v1)

def xtea_decrypt(key,block,n=32,endian="!"):
    v0,v1 = struct.unpack(endian+"2L",block)
    k = struct.unpack(endian+"4L",key)
    delta,mask = 0x9e3779b9L,0xffffffffL
    sum = (delta * n) & mask
    for round in range(n):
        v1 = (v1 - (((v0<<4 ^ v0>>5) + v0) ^ (sum + k[sum>>11 & 3]))) & mask
        sum = (sum - delta) & mask
        v0 = (v0 - (((v1<<4 ^ v1>>5) + v1) ^ (sum + k[sum & 3]))) & mask
    return struct.pack(endian+"2L",v0,v1)
```

> Attribution, code from: ActiveState Code » Recipes